# PHP ForEach Loop With Bootstrap prints list of 50 (all the same) where only 6 exist in DB

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

This is some Bootstrap HTML where I need to create multiple blocks like a table but it just grabs the first item in the DB and prints 50 of them.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to mingle the php code and html code so it works correctly.

```
<section id="latest-news" class="latest-news-section">
<div class="container">

<?php
include_once ('mysql.inc.php');
$ix       = $_POST['i'];
$sql = "SELECT * from deposits WHERE d_userid = '$ix' ORDER BY _productionid ASC";
$query        = @mysql_query($sql);
$outcome        = @mysql_fetch_array($query);
foreach ($outcome as $result1){

?>
```

This part comes out nicely formatted, but the only data is the first item in the DB, and there are 50 copies made

```
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
               <div class="latest-post">
                        <img src="assets/images/<?php echo     $outcome['d_picture'] ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                       <h4>Your ST1 <?php echo $outcome['d_firstname'] ?></h4>
                      <p>Prod ID <?php echo $outcome['d_productionid'] ?></p>
                       <p>Color: <?php echo $outcome['d_color'] ?><br />
                       Equip: <?php echo $outcome['d_equip'] ?><br />
                     Custom: <?php echo $outcome['d_custom'] ?></p>
                     <a class="btn btn-primary">View More</a>
                   </div>
                </div>



<?

}
@mysql_close;
?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `while($outcome = mysql_fetch_array($query))`. Also, it's 2018, stop using `mysql_*`!

Comment: I can explain part of the problem.. in the printing section of your code, you need to be using `$result1` instead of '$outcome'  That explains why it is repeating the first row.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: The while() thing definitely helped.  Thanks to everyone for the tips!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use $result1 and not $outcome
ex: $result1['d_picture']